# How to convert all lines to lower case while loading from a Path?

Tags: java, file, path, lowercase

I'm loading a file from a Path.  The problem is the file has words that have CAPS.  I would like to load the file and convert each entry to lowerCase at the same time.

I know I have to add toLowerCase() but I'm not sure where to do this.  I want to make sure all my entries into dictTest are lowerCase.

## Code

```
private static void loadDictWords(Path dictFile) throws Exception{
        dictTest = Files.lines(dictFile).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
```

Comment: That is not a complete code. What type is your `dictTest` variable?

Comment: ArrayList of Strings

Answer (score 2):

Use a map operation.

```
Files.lines(dictFile).map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```